# Supabase Postgres quesion can't delete

Tags: postgresql, permissions, supabase

I have an odd problem with deleting a user that I created on my server with this code:

```
 const { data, error } = await supabaseAdminClient.auth.admin.createUser({
            email,
            password,
            email_confirm: true,
            user_metadata: {
                username,
                avatar_url,
                website,
                first_name,
                last_name,
                email
            }
        })
```

It works all without any issue. The user is created in the auth.user table and I wrote a function which triggers and populates my user table in the public scheme.
When I try to delete the user however with this piece of code:

```
        const { data, error } = await supabaseAdminClient.auth.admin.deleteUser(id)
        console.log(error)
```

I get an error. The user is not being deleted from the auth.schema nor from my public.user table.
This is what comes up in the logs.

```
  {
    "message": null,
    "timestamp": "2023-09-16T14:43:35Z",
    "__MONOTONIC_TIMESTAMP": null,
    "CODE_FUNC": null,
    "instance_id": null,
    "status": null,
    "_CMDLINE": null,
    "method": "DELETE",
    "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP": null,
    "CODE_FILE": null,
    "EXECUTABLE": null,
    "_EXE": null,
    "UNIT": null,
    "level": "error",
    "_COMM": null,
    "duration": null,
    "issuer": null,
    "_LINE_BREAK": null,
    "_SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": null,
    "msg": "500: Database error deleting user",
    "action": null,
    "login_method": null,
    "_UID": null,
    "host": "db-qchkhacihysnmntfgerc",
    "PRIORITY": null,
    "_CAP_EFFECTIVE": null,
    "_PID": null,
    "INVOCATION_ID": null,
    "_SYSTEMD_UNIT": null,
    "source_type": null,
    "SYSLOG_FACILITY": null,
    "request_id": null,
    "CODE_LINE": null,
    "path": "/admin/users/883ee5fa-3109-4e90-879f-897ee29c0966",
    "component": "api",
    "project": null,
    "user_id": "883ee5fa-3109-4e90-879f-897ee29c0966",
    "auth_event": [
      {
        "action": "user_deleted",
        "actor_id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "actor_name": null,
        "actor_username": "service_role",
        "actor_via_sso": false,
        "log_type": "team",
        "traits": [
          {
            "channel": null,
            "provider": null,
            "user_email": "whatever@ame.com",
            "user_id": "883ee5fa-3109-4e90-879f-897ee29c0966",
            "user_phone": null
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "args": [],
    "referer": "http://localhost:3000",
    "factor_id": null,
    "provider": null,
    "client_id": null,
    "remote_addr": "79.168.4.191",
    "_SYSTEMD_SLICE": null,
    "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID": null,
    "header": null,
    "_MACHINE_ID": null,
    "_AUDIT_LOGINUID": null,
    "_TRANSPORT": null,
    "_SELINUX_CONTEXT": null,
    "MESSAGE_ID": null,
    "__REALTIME_TIMESTAMP": null,
    "metadata": [],
    "_STREAM_ID": null,
    "metering": null,
    "time": null,
    "_GID": null,
    "_BOOT_ID": null,
    "SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER": null,
    "_AUDIT_SESSION": null,
    "error": "ERROR: permission denied for schema public (SQLSTATE 42501)"
  }
```

I can only delete it by typing in the SQL directly into the console. I am pretty sure its a rights/ permission issue but I am compared the rights management to a fresh project/ tried out the stuff and its seems the same.

[image: Supabase rights management dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

I found the error.

When I defined my function to delete the user I forgot to select Security Definer instead of Security invoker.

When editing in the Supabase UI one can not change the permission the function runs on so it was an out of sight out of mind scenario.